# How to use the Django Usurena "mugshot" template variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use Userena in our Django website, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the template tag to display the mugshot.  I have tried the following to spit out the URL within an image tag:

```
<img src="{{ owner_profile.get_mugshot_url }}">
```

and

```
<img src="{{ profile.get_mugshot_url }}">
```

Anyone have some insight??

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what Userna is, but unless you've explicitly passed `profile` to your template context, it's not going to be available.

If you've implemented the standard django `profile`, you'd access it via `user.get_profile.foo` assuming the `auth` `context_processor` has been added to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: Thanks Yuji - I was not passing 'profile' to the template... rookie mistake, I know ;)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on alican answer, just put following code in your template:

```
<img src="{{ user.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to display Userena profile image(mugshot) in your template. Use appropriate username to filter the required user.

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def my_view(request):
        profile = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username).get_profile()
        return render_to_response('template.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here I have rendered this variable "profile" to the template "template.html". Include following code in your template to display mugshot image.

**template.html**

```
    <img src="{{ profile.get_mugshot_url }}" />
```

It worked for me. Hope it will work for you too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ user.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}
```

Comment: How do you get **user** in views? from userena or django authentication backend? Explain them more clearly to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way it worked for me:

`{{ user.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}`

But make sure you use `render` as opposed to `render_to_response` for each of the pages that you'll be pulling it in (ex: views.py):

`from django.shortcuts import render`

`return render(request, 'sometemplate.html', {"name": "some_var"}, )`

Here's how I did it, pulling in the mugshot for the navbar dropdown (ex: sometemplate.html):

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle user-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img class="user-thumbnail img-circle" src="{{ user.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}" alt="" />
            Hi, {{ user.username }}
            <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' user.username %}"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> Profile</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="/accounts/signout"><i class="icon-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="/accounts/signin">Log in</a></li>  
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```