# how to display userena contents in the templates of other app

Tags: python, django

I want to display mugshot and background from Userena in one of my APP namely **UserBackground** 's Template.But it seems to me that it is not a easy task to do for a person who is really new in Django like me.I have tried to do this several times but its not working.This is view which resides in my **UserBackground** , where i have tried to capture the Mugshot,but i failed.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Photo.models import photo #Photo Model of the App  

def userphoto(request,user_id):    
    user = Photo.objects.filter(user = user_id)
    user_mugshot = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=user_id)

    context = RequestContext(request)
    ctx_dict = {'user': user,'user_mugshot' : user_mugshot}

    return render_to_response('photo/user_portfolio.html',locals(),ctx_dict,context)
    #return HttpResponse(ctx_photo)
```

and this is the urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/user_photo/$',views.userphoto,name = 'userporrfolio')
```

i write those codes in my View according to this link.

[How to use the Django Usurena "mugshot" template variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102968/how-to-use-the-django-usurena-mugshot-template-variable)

i am not sure is it right way to capture Mugshot from userena app in another app.

Comment: What are you passing to the template? Have you followed the advice in the answers to the SO question you linked to?

Comment: yes i have did according to the answer of arulmr in my template