# how to use mugshot of my web users outside of their profile page(django-userena)

Tags: django

Hello I'm using django userena and I could've figured out most part. The only part that I'm struggling is using mugshot out side of edit profile page. I tried using

`<a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' post.moderator.username %}"><img src="{{post.moderator.profile.get_mugshot_url }}" /></span></a>`

but this doesn't show anything. I googled around and tried few things but so lost now. What should I do to display the mugshot of the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Django Usurena "mugshot" template variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102968/how-to-use-the-django-usurena-mugshot-template-variable)

Comment: @LaurIvan, that's the one I exactly followed

Comment: Hmm. can you add the model?